# PHP/HTML - Spaghetti, fastest code for the server

Tags: php, html

I have a big page with much spaghetti code. I'm not sure which solution is faster for the server.

The first solution

```
<div> ... many html code ....

 <?
         if(isset($ubo['day']['xxl']['0']))
         {
             $firstHit = $ubo['day']['xxl']['0']['title'];
            echo "<div style=\"cursor:pointer;\">$firstHit </div>";
         }
 ?>

 ... many html code .... </div>
```

this solution ( I use ' instead of "  )

```
<?
     // many php code
     if(isset($ubo['day']['xxl']['0']))
     {
          $firstHit = $ubo['day']['xxl']['0']['title'];   
     }

     // one echo with all html code 
     echo "<div> ... many html code ....
           <div style='cursor:pointer;'>$firstHit </div>
            ... many html code .... </div>";

?>
```

or this solution

```
<?
     // many php code
     if(isset($ubo['day']['xxl']['0']))
     {
          $firstHit = $ubo['day']['xxl']['0']['title'];   
     }

     // one echo with all html code
     echo "<div> ... many html code ....
           <div style=\"cursor:pointer;\">$firstHit </div>
            ... many html code .... </div>";

?>
```

Comment: Your second and third solution are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the solutions presented, I would say that the first is probably best. General rule is that you should put as much into strait HTML as possible. This is both for the developer's sake as well as the server's. Stuff outside of `<?php ?>` is basically raw data which, while it still needs to be parsed on some level, can basically be served to the user straight up.

If anything, you may want to refine it further:

```html
<!-- as a note: in all of your examples except the first, this div exists.
     In the first it only exists if the isset returns true. -->
<div style="cursor:pointer;">
    <php?
    if(isset($ubo['day']['xxl']['0']))
    {
         echo $ubo['day']['xxl']['0']['title'];
    } ?>
</div>
```

You also could probably optimize through storing `$ubo['day']['xxl']` in some local variable elsewhere on the page.

Comment: doesn't really matter if you use opcode cache... and if you don't use it but still trying to optimize minor PHP details you're doing something really stupid.

Comment: @yi_H It is still good practice -- I always cache arrays to avoid long series of lookups.

Comment: I never ever do low level code optimizations like that, if I stored the array lookup in a local var I would do it only for code readability (which is 10x more important for me). BTW this looks like a static content (for a day), just cache the whole thing and do not optimize the generator for the content since it's going to be rarely used.

Comment: @cwallenpoole -1 because it's absolutely not the best answer here, you're just validating the fact that this kind of optimization is important but it's not ! if you have a LOT of traffic and this become important, you'll be able to ask to the 300 engineer working for you to optimize it.

Answer (score 2):

Practically, it doesn't really matter. What matters is that your code is maintainable and clean. You should look into using a PHP framework like CodeIgniter or CakePHP to make your code more well-structured.

Answer (score 1):

You should have as little HTML inside PHP `echo`/`print` statements as possible; it is good to close PHP tags and just have the natural HTML.  This is because the parser won't travel through the `echo`/`print` statement and and parse it.  Thus, your first solution is certainly the best in terms of speed.

Comment: if you use opcode cache, parsing costs are amortized to zero, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have performance problem ? If no don't bother about "better for the server" and do "better for your code" instead.

And i'd say that all this is the same, most of the performance are due to I/O (sql query/web service, hard disk) not syntax details.

So do the best code for yourself you'll see later about performance.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution might be faster than the first, because you are sending the content only once and it also looks a little better (PHP is more separated from HTML).

However performance difference between all 3 solutions will be very small and you really should't put attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the hint "premature code optimization is evil" :-) I dont think that it makes a (big)  difference what you use in your given code. It would be much better to have a clean code separation in mvc. Then you can use a template engine which supports caching for your massive html code and there's no need to output it every time with an echo! Besides this performance optimization has much more effect on DB-issues, your general code structure and the code at client side. For example, avoid inline css styles to reduce transferred html code.

Answer (score 0):

- do you use PHP opcode cache?
- do you use memcached for generated subpages?
- have you optimized your database queries?
- do you use icongroup images? do you compress JS and CSS?
- have you *really* run out of all the low hanging fruits?